# Creating a $4 \times 4$ square grid using $5$ pieces of $8$-inch wires

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, eulerian-path

We would like to create a $4$-by-$4$ square grid using pieces of wire such that the sides of the squares are $1$ inch and we are not allowed to cut the wires. Is it possible to create the grid by using $5$ pieces of wire of length $8$ inch each?

I know that this is not possible, but I am stuck at proving it. I think it is Euler tour related, and the grid itself should contain no Euler tour since there are more than $2$ vertices with odd number of degrees. Any hint on this problem?

Comment: I think the OP has provided enough context for his/her attempt.  The idea about Eulerian paths is very relevant to the solution.  I don't think that downvotes are warranted (and unfair in my opinion).  Just because an attempt is short doesn't mean it is not a good attempt.

Comment: I wonder: if there are $6$ pieces of wire with positive-integer length $n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_6$ s.t. $n_1+n_2+\ldots+n_6=40$, does it guarantee that you can create this $4\times 4$ grid?  At least there is no contradiction if you use an Euler-path argument.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool In fact, if there are 8 pieces of 5 inch wires, we can create such grid.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool I conjecture that {30, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2} is impossible

Comment: *Chinese postman problem*

Comment: @RobPratt similar, but normally the postman isn't allowed to just teleport four times arbitrarily.

Comment: @JohnDvorak I think you are right.  So I am curious what is the smallest positive $k$ such that whenever there are $k$ pieces of wire with positive-integer lengths $n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k$ s.t. $\sum_{i=1}^kn_i=40$, we can always make the $4\times 4$ grid.  It seems the OP claimed that $k\le 8$ (is there a proof?).  And you showed that $k\ge 7$.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool I do not have a written proof for k<=8, but I can draw a graph such that 8x5 inch wires can form the grid. If you bend each wire into "L" shape such that one side is 1 inch and the other side is 4 inch, you can put four wires in horizontal and vertical orientation and form the grid.

Comment: I conjecture the following: in my proposed problem about minimum number $k$ of wire, $k=7$ is the smallest possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

- How many graph edges do you have available? How many do you need?
- Therefore, how many edges can be doubled?
- Given that restriction, how many wire ends do you need?
- How many wire ends do you have available?

Comment: In this case we have 40 edges, and the wires can also provide 40 edges. Therefore, the total number of degrees of all vertices should be 80. Since we have 5 wires, there are 10 wire ends. However, I don't understand the connection between number of edges and the number of wire ends I need.

Comment: You are on the right trail regarding odd-degree vertices. Can you generalize the restriction about Euler paths to multi-path covers? Think about why the restriction for Euler paths exists.

Comment: This problem basically asks to partition the grid into 5 components such that each component is a path. According to the Euler path restriction, a Euler path can have either 0 or 2 vertices with odd number of degrees. In this problem, there are 12 vertices with odd number of edges, but the given wires can only take at most 10 such vertices. Is this the right idea? Thanks for your hints.

Comment: That is correct